# displaying related articles according to tag in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags

I am trying to show related articles on show page of article. When user views any particular article, all related articles in db should be displayed on that page ( in right side bar) according tag( as every article has at-least one tag).My app has relation between tag and article (please below).

articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :is_user_admin, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :destroy]
    def is_user_admin
      redirect_to(action: :index) unless current_user.try(:is_admin?) 
      return false 
    end

    def index
      @articles = Article.all(:order => "created_at DESC")
      @article_titles = Article.first(10)

      @tags = Tag.all
    end

    def show
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
      @article = Article.new
    end

    def create
      @article = Article.new(params[:article])
      @article.user_id = current_user.id

      if @article.save
        flash[:success] = "article created!"
        redirect_to article_path(@article)

      else
        render 'new' 
      end 
    end

    def destroy
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
      @article.destroy

      redirect_to action:  'index'  
    end

    def edit
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])

      if @article.update_attributes(params[:article])
       flash.notice = "Article '#{@article.title}' Updated!"
       redirect_to article_path(@article)

      else 
        render 'edit'
      end
  end
end
```

tags_controller.rb

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  #before_filter :user_signed_in, only: [:destroy]

  def index
    @tags = Tag.all
  end

  def show
    @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130411074056) do
  create_table "articles", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "comments", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "article_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "taggings", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "tag_id"
    t.integer  "article_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  add_index "taggings", ["article_id"], :name => "index_taggings_on_article_id"
  add_index "taggings", ["tag_id"], :name => "index_taggings_on_tag_id"

  create_table "tags", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end
```

articles/show.html.erb :- where i need to display related articles when user views any particular article based on tag

Currently articles/show.html.erb page has tag(S) name and I want to display all artilces with same tag in db to display on this page (right side bar). Any idea how to implement this relation to fetch out related articles and where to write this logic and how to implement in views.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using [acts_as_taggable_on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on), what you want is easy to achieve using the following code

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @related_articles = Article.tagged_with(@article.tag_list, any: true)
end
```

Since you rolled up your own implementation, you'd have to manually do the fetch.

First get a list of all the tags of the article. That would be `@article.tag_ids`.

Next, get a list of articles associated to those tag ids

```
@related_articles = Article
  .joins(:taggings)
  .where('articles.id != ?', @article.id)
  .where(taggings: { tag_id: @article.tag_ids })
```

Comment: hi jvnill,thanks for your response. but I have not used "acts_as_taggable_on" plugin. Any idea how to achieve it with this plugin.I have association in db between articles and tags table as you can see in question. any help would be appreciating.

Comment: hi jvnill, thanks for your suggestion. but how can i use "@related_articles" in views (articles/show.html.erb). any suggestion.

Comment: when i implement your suggestion, it gives me ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Articles#show

Showing /Users/harshaldhumal/Desktop/kuta/billi/app/views/articles/show.html.erb where line #56 raised:

SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: id: SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "taggings"."article_id" = "articles"."id" WHERE "taggings"."tag_id" IN (17, 18) AND (id != 18) error. I think @article.tag_ids  is wrong. It should be @article.tag_id. When i tried with @article.tag_id, it says "NoMethodError in ArticlesController#show

undefined method `tag_id'"

Comment: ah change `id` to `articles.id`. look at the updated answer.  you should work through a tutorial on rails if you want to know how to use an instance variable in a view :)

Comment: hi jvnill, A big thanks man. updated code works like magic. but I has one problem that It displays each similar article twice. Here is my code in views:- <% @related_articles.each do | related_article | %>
   <% if !related_article.nil? %>
   <div style="margin-top:15px; margin-left:8px">  <%= link_to related_article.title,  article_path(related_article) %></div>
    <% end %>
   <% end %>
Any suggestion.

Comment: hi VSiingh, a quick fix would be to add `.uniq` at the end of the chain.  The problem most probably lies in `.joins`.  I don't see anything wrong with you code :)

Comment: hi jvnill, I jsut checked that nothing wrong with your code. Problem lies with my code.It is related how i store tag related to articles.a big thanks for your responese.